# How to add .exe file dependency so as to create a single runnable Jar

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, eclipse

I have written a Selenium Webdriver Java (in Eclipse) automation test Script which I run in the Chrome Browser. The script depends on a chromedriver.exe which I have added in my project dependency folder.

I am able to add the dependent .jar files in runnable jar but not .exe files. Is there any way to export a single runnable jar which also includes the chromedriver.exe file.

Comment: have you tried exporting your project?

Comment: Yes. I able to export the project and the dependent jar files as a single runnable jar. But the Chromedriver.exe is not included in the runnable jar.

Answer (score 1):

That is actually a sort of bad practice to distribute `WebDriver.exe` within your java program, since it will stale after the browser will get updated. You also won't be able to run the `exe` file straight from the `jar` file. However if you have no options I can suggest the following way:

1. Put your `exe` file to `resources` folder
2. Within the code implement copying the file from `resources` to some place in the file system.
3. Execute that file from the code
4. Build `jar` (`exe` file will be placed as a `resource` to your `jar`)

Below is a simple example on how you can achieve points 2 and 3:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException {

        // Copy file from resources to file system (path taken from the command line argument)

        InputStream is = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("phantomjs.exe");
        File exeFile = new File(args[0]);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(exeFile);
        byte bytes[] = new byte[1000];
        int k = 0;
        while((k = is.read(bytes)) != -1){
            fos.write(bytes, 0, k);
        }
        fos.close(); // Do not forget to close the outputstream, otherwise your code will be holding the file and it won't be possible to execute it

        // Below is just an example on how you can execute the file after copying
        List<String> commands = new ArrayList<String>();    //
        commands.add(args[0]);                              //  Start file with argument
        commands.add("--help");                             //
        Process p = new ProcessBuilder().command(commands).start();
        InputStream i = p.getInputStream();         //
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(i);           //
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()){              //  Print the output of the file
            System.out.println(scanner.nextLine()); //
        }                                           //
    }

}
```

In this example we have our `phantomjs.exe` file in `resource` folder. We also take the destination for the file copying from command line arguments. So the way how to execute the `jar` will look like:

```
java -jar mysuper.jar c:/Temp/pjs.exe
```

Comment: Hi...I almost forgot I had asked this question...Will definitely try and let you know...Thanks for your reply :-)

Comment: @Alok the last month there is almost no interesting questions in the community so I'm searching for old interesting questions having no answers like yours one :)